# Displaying a Scratch Project (.SB2) file within a Delphi EXE FIle

Tags: delphi, scratch

I would like to Display a Scratch Project (.SB2) file within my Delphi EXE file. I would like to know if it is possible to display and build the Scratch Project into your Delphi Project.

I wish to make a small game in Scratch and then use the game within my Delphi Application without the need of the Scratch 2 IDE. Perhaps a 3rd party delphi tool or component or something that can help me achieve this would also be very nice. So basically I want to host the Scratch game within my Delphi app.

Is this possible? How can this be done? (I am using Delphi 10.3.2 Rio and Scratch 2 Offline Editor)

Comment: Scratch 2.0 [is written](https://github.com/LLK/scratch-flash) in [ActionScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) (for [Adobe Flash Player](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Player)). I'm not familiar with Delphi, but [this tutorial](http://delphi.about.com/od/graphics/l/aa040103a.htm) suggests you can embed Flash content in your Delphi applications. This is pretty specialised work though, and getting distant from the topic of game development. Perhaps it would be best to [ask the Scratch developers](https://scratch.mit.edu/contact-us/) or [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

Turbowarp.org can convert scratch projects to .exe if that is what you mean. You need to upload your project and go to package project. Scroll down and there will be a bunch of things you can convert your project to.

For .exe I would use the Electron [Your Computer Type] Application.

Comment: It's not clear to me from this answer how does converting the Scratch project into a `.exe` solve OP's problem of displaying the game from within the Delphi generated `.exe`; what additional steps need to be taken to accomplish the goal as stated OP's question?